# CDI bean in JAVA EE

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

Recently I've seen CDI bean used in DDD Sample Project "Cargo Tracker". Where a CDI bean was used with @ApplicationScoped annotation with Entity Manager for data access repository.
My Questions are as follows:

1. Is it a good practice to use Entity Manager with CDI bean instead a @stateless bean(EJB)?
2. What benefit we get by using CDI bean with Entity Manager without container managed  approach?
3. Exactly when should we use CDI bean instead stateless container managed bean?

Comment: This is still a container managed approach, as long as its injected using `@PersistenceContext`

Comment: Try asking one constructive question per Question, not a bunch of questions with a somewhat subjective flavor. Moreover, the answer depends on Java EE version used and the concrete code. Include this information in the question as well instead of referring an off-site resource. The potential answerer is very unlikely going to lookup the sample project for you, and you should make sure that the question is self-containing in such way that it's answerable without the need to lookup an external site which may not necessarily exist anymore later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EJB >= CDI - with EJB you've got some additional features like extended life cycle, transactions, etc.

The general approach should be: start with "standard CDI" and if you need additional features use EJB.

I would ask on your questions: it depends :) on your requirements. In my opinion there is no common answer.